# making a defective triangluar matrix to non defective

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Investigate the eigenvalue problem of a triangular matrix whose diagonal elements are all equal. Show that by a small modification of the diagonal elements, all the eigenvalues can be made distinct and that the eigenvectors thus created are very near to each other in magnitude and direction, collapsing into one as the perturbation goes to zero.

This was a question taken from the book Linear differential operators by Cornelius Lanczos.

For me, the eigenvalue is repeating even after adding a small variation to the diagonal elements $a_{ii}+\epsilon$

How to solve this problem.?

Comment: why not change the adjustment to something like $a_{ii}+i\epsilon$?

Comment: That essentially means different epsilons for the diagonal elements, right? but from the question, "a small modification of the diagonal elements " means the perturbation given has to be the same, is it so?